# jquery loads the same posts instead of appending new ones

Tags: jquery

I am able to display first two posts and a button "Load more" but when I press "Load more" button it still gets the same two posts. 
Could you please have a look on my code and help me to find the mistake.

```
            $("#load_more_posts").click(function() { 
                var offset = offset+limit; 
                $.post('cont/get_list', {limit: limit, offset: offset}, function (data) {
                    if (data.message !== undefined) {
                        $( "#list_is_not_got").text(data.message);
                    } else {

                         var item = $('<div>');  

                        $.each(data.results, function(i, res) {

                            var info = $('<p>'); 

                            info.html(res.post_text+'<hr>');               

                            item.append(head,info);
                        });             
                        $("#list_is_got").html(item);           
                    }
                }, "json");
               });
```

Comment: This almost seem a bit more of a backend issue. Can you paste your backend code too? What response does the server bring back?

Comment: server brings back the first two posts as I mentioned in my question. The problem is in my jquery code. {"results":[{"post_text":"good"},{"post_text":"cool”}]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably to do with failure to increment `offset`.

Try changing :

```
var offset = offset + limit;
```

to :

```
offset += limit;
```